# cloudera-scm-server is dead and pid file exists

Tags: 14.04, cloudera-manager

I am new to Ubuntu and Cloudera as well. I have installed Cloudera manager (5.7.1) on Ubuntu 14.04 from the documentation given on Cloudera site. I am not able to connect to http://localhost:7180 . I checked the status of cloudera-scm-server by using `sudo service cloudera-scm-server status` command.

It was **cloudera-scm-server is dead and pid file exists** so I restarted the cloudera-scm-server after deleting the file. After restart server was showing status running. Then I again tried to connect to http://localhost:7180. As soon as I did that server status again changed to **cloudera-scm-server is dead and pid file exists**.

I found this output for command

```
tail -f /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.out
```

> ... 34 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate the Cloudera Manager log file in the log4j settings at com.cloudera.server.web.cmf.logs.LogUtil.getServerLogfile(LogUtil.java:34) at com.cloudera.server.cmf.log.components.ServerLogFetcherImpl.(ServerLogFetcherImpl.java:77) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126) ... 36 more

Can someone help me figuring it out? Thanks in advance